# I am tryimg to download a pdf file which is on my webserver, However my file is corrupted when it is downloaded

Tags: java, android

```
private Boolean downloadAndSaveFile(String server, int portNumber,String user, String password) throws IOException {

    FTPClient ftp = null;
    // path of a file which is on a web server
    String remoteFile1 = "/public_html/1/c language/Unit_1_HTML_and_Forms.pdf";
    // Path of my device
    File downloadFile1 = new File("/storage/emulated/0/a/new.pdf");
    try {
        ftp = new FTPClient();
        ftp.connect(server, portNumber);
        ftp.login(user, password);
        ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        System.out.println("Reached passive");
        OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile1));
        System.out.println("Stream Created");
        boolean success = ftp.retrieveFile(remoteFile1, outputStream1);
        System.out.println(success);
        return true;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
        if (ftp != null) {
            ftp.logout();
            ftp.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the retriveFile(...) does not close the stream. Try flushing it and closing it (outputStream1) after returns true